# Multiplying a 2d array in its entirety c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a 2d array that is double another 2d array. For example, if I had an array that had a height of 2 and a width of 2, the new one would have double the amount. Same goes for its contents: if the original array consisted of `1,0,2,0` I would want the new array to consist of `1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0`.
Does anybody know how to do this, or if its possible?

```
int height = 2;
int width = 2;
int[,] arr1 = new int[height,width];
arr1[0,0] = 0;
arr1[0, 1] = 2;
arr1[1, 0] = 1;
arr1[1, 1] = 0;
int newheight = height * 2;
int newwidth = width * 2;
int[,] newarr = new int[newheight, newwidth];
```

Comment: "_if I had an array that had a height of 2 and a width of two, the new one would have double the amount._" -> double the amount of what? width ? height? both? The example "1,0,2,0" --> "1,1,0,0,2,2,0,0" seems to infer it's either height or width but  **not** both, whereas what you coded infers it **is** both. So, there is a contradiction in your description.

Comment: looks like you already have code for creating the arrayin the double size. For copying the data, I don't think there's a better way than two `for` loops.

Comment: If Ian's answer is right, you're basically performing "nearest-neighbor interpolation".

Answer (score 1):

So if your original looks like:

```
0 2
1 0
```

And you want your new one to look like this?

```
0 0 2 2
0 0 2 2
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
```

Sure, then just use every value twice:

```
int[,] newarr = new int[newheight, newwidth];
for(int i=0;i<newheight;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<newwidth;j++)
    {
        // Divide index by 2 to ensure we don't overflow original array
        newarr[i,j] = arr[i/2, j/2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ians answer is fine, well apart from using jagged array syntax on a multidimensional array (fixed now).

For academic purposes, I tried to quickly put together a solution that could deal with any size and any dimension.

Unfortunately there is no generic constraint for `System.Array` so we have to live with casting (somewhere). Also, It could likely be made a little more efficient.

**Given**

```
public static Array Inflate<T>(Array source, int size)
{
   // get the lengths of each dimension multiplied by the inflation size
   var lengths = Enumerable
      .Range(0, source.Rank)
      .Select(x => source.GetLength(x) * size)
      .ToArray();

   var indices = new int[source.Rank]; // this is the index map of what we want to set
   var originals = new int[source.Rank]; // this is the index map of the array to interpolate from

   // this is how we create an array of with arbitrary dimensions
   var instance = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), lengths);

   do
   {
      // GetValue and SetValue takes an index map
      instance.SetValue(source.GetValue(originals), indices); 

      // this increments each element in the dimension
      // when it hits the last element, goes to the next dimension
      // and increments that, setting the last to 0
      // you can think of it like an minutes, hour, day, type clock
      for (var i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
      {
         indices[i]++;
         originals[i] = indices[i] / size; // original index
         if (indices[i] < lengths[i])
            break;
         indices[i] = originals[i] = 0;
      }
      // if we are back to 0, we have finished
   } while (indices.Any(x => x != 0));
   return  instance;
}
```

**Test Data**

```
var arr1 = new int[2, 2, 2];
arr1[0, 0, 0] = 0;
arr1[1, 0, 0] = 1;
arr1[0, 1, 0] = 2;
arr1[1, 1, 0] = 3;
arr1[0, 0, 1] = 4;
arr1[1, 0, 1] = 5;
arr1[0, 1, 1] = 6;
arr1[1, 1, 1] = 7;
```

**Usage**

```
// inflate a 3 dimensional array by 2 in each dimension
var result = (int[,,])Inflate<int>(arr1, 2);
```

**Printing the results**

Word of warning this is a brain twister, as conceptually we are trying to print a third dimension on to a 2 dimensional console. So I am basically just slicing the 3rd dimension (z)

```
for (var z = 0; z < result.GetLength(2); z++)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"z = {z}");
   for (int x = 0; x < result.GetLength(0); x++)
   {
      for (int y = 0; y < result.GetLength(1); y++)
      {
         Console.Write(result[x,y,z] + " ");
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
z = 0

0 0 2 2
0 0 2 2
1 1 3 3
1 1 3 3

z = 1

0 0 2 2
0 0 2 2
1 1 3 3
1 1 3 3

z = 2

4 4 6 6
4 4 6 6
5 5 7 7
5 5 7 7

z = 3

4 4 6 6
4 4 6 6
5 5 7 7
5 5 7 7
```